# how to assign a shared pointer of type structure to a shared pointer of class type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In the below function, `info` is a class which contains `getHDDList` function and `HDDList` is a structure. but when I assign the output of `getHDDList` to hdd, it says `no operator "=" matches this operands`:

```
HDDList* smc_getHDDList(Authorization* autho)
{
    HDDList retVal;
    //HDDList* hdd = new HDDList;
    std::shared_ptr<info> inf (new info(autho));
    std::shared_ptr<HDDList> hdd ;
    try
    {
        //inf.get()->getHDDList();
        //hdd = inf.get()->getHDDList();
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
    {
        THROW_EXCEPTION
    }
    return hdd;
}
```

this is my `HDDList` structure :

```
struct HDDList
{
    const char* name;
    double totalSize;
    double freeSize;
    double usedSize;
};
```

and this is `getHDDList` function :

```
HDDList* info::getHDDList()
{
    int num;
    num = std::stoi(numberOfHDDs());
    HDDList* list = new HDDList[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        list[i].name = listOfHDDs(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have used shared pointer because when I was using raw pointers and delete pointers before returning, I had problem in receiving the structure( it didn't return first member of structure). 
How can I assign `getHDDList`'s output to `hdd`?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please. Without, it's hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: A shared pointer to a pointer makes no sense. And using a shared pointer for the `HDDList` object makes no sense either, since you're not using any of the ownership semantics of shared pointers, and just return the raw pointer. In short, don't use shared pointer for `hdd`. Actually, I don't see the need for a shared pointer for `inf` either, or the use of a pointer at all. Why not simply `return info(autho).getHDDList()`?

Comment: it works fine. thanks. but what if I want to put `info(autho).getHDDList()`'s output into something like `hdd` object and then return `hdd`? shouldn't it be pointer ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Why all these pointers?

Comment: output of `getHDDList` is a list of names. @bipll

Comment: the ownership is a bit confusing in smc_getHDDList, why do you use shared_ptr ? using a unique_ptr would maybe be a better choice. then just return  hdd.release()

Comment: I replaced `unique_ptr`, but when I use `hdd = inf.get()->getHDDList();`, it gives the same error about operator. @AndersK

Comment: The return type of `smc_getHDDList` is `HDDList*`. This is incompatible with `std::shared_ptr<HDDList>`, which is the type of the local variable `hdd`. You need to pick your ownership semantics.

Comment: Besides, unless this assignment/exercise is about pointers and manual handling of allocations, you should be using `std::vector<HDDList>` instead of all those pointers. Then you won't even need to worry about "smart pointers".

Comment: @fa7eme and — what?

Comment: my output should be "C standard". @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Another weird thing: If the `THROW_EXCEPTION` macro just rethrows the current exception, then why `try ... catch` in the `smc_getHDDList` function?

Comment: emm what do you mean? how should I correct that? I wanted to catch the exception that is thrown from `listOFHDDs`.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: But you don't *do* anything in the `catch`, except (possibly) throw the exception again.

Comment: I want to rethrow exception if anything happened. am I doing it wrong? @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

Could probably try something like :

```
hdd.reset(inf->getHDDList());
```

You'd need to update the return type if you take this route.

Comment: the same problem when I used raw pointers. first argument is null.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this code, so let me see if we can get this right.

First of all, in your struct HDDList you have a const pointer name; where does this point to?

I think you would be better off if you declared it as a `std::string` so that it is self-contained when the node is destroyed.

```
struct HDDList
{
  std::string name;
  double totalSize;
  double freeSize;
  double usedSize;
};
```

Otherwise if the name points to some allocated string you will need to handle that as well a destructor in HHDList or in a custom deleter for unique_ptr.

You want to create an array of HDDList in your function getHDDLists()

```
HDDList* info::getHDDList() {...}
```

Notice that you are not returning the size of the array. So the caller has no way of knowing how long the array is because it just gets a pointer to where the array starts.

(If you don't have some secret marker in your data that you haven't mentioned).

So let's add the size and return an array wrapped in a unique_ptr:

```
std::unique_ptr<HDDList[]> info::getHDDList(int& num)
{
  num = std::stoi(numberOfHDDs()); 
  auto list = std::make_unique<HDDList[]>(num);
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  {
    list[i].name = listOfHDDs(i);
  }
  return list;
}
```

In your caller function you have now the information of how big the array plus the array wrapped in a smart pointer:

```
HDDList* smc_getHDDList(Authorization* autho)
{
  auto inf = std::make_unique<info>(autho);
  std::unique_ptr<HDDList[]> hdd;
  try
  {
    int hddSize{0};
    hdd = inf->getHDDList(hddSize);
    ...
  }
  catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
  {
    // write out exception
    // rethrow if you want
  }
  return hdd;
}
```